# Scaffolding external EF 6 model classes into MVC 5 controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller

I am trying to fix an MVC 5 site(created by someone else) using Visual Studio 2012 with the Web Tools 2013 extension to allow me to work with mvc 5. The Models for this site were created in an separate project and solution using EF6. I have added a reference to the external dll form the main MVC project and I am trying to get visual studio to do the controller and view scaffolding (Like I've seen done, and done myself a few times, when the models are in the same project) but when I right click Controllers -> Add -> controller -> MVC 5 Controller with etc. using Entity Framework, my external project classes do not appear under the Model Class drop down so I can select the appropriate model and context class for the new controller.

Is there a way to have the external classes show up under the add controller dialog box? If more information is needed I will try to oblige, but I am fairly new to MVC as a whole.

Comment: Attempt to use the 'Rebuild Solution' option in the Build file menu  as-is with your reference to the external .dll available. I have had similar issues and the 'Rebuild Solution' did the trick.

Comment: Sadly, I've already tried that and still don't get any options to use my external library. For now I've had to move the code from the external into the MVC project just to get some traction, but this is not a viable permanent solution.

Comment: Similar problem here, but with asp.net WebApi2 and VS2017